# Packet capturing in l3fwd

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I am performing a dpdk experiment. In my setup, I have two physical machines, Host1 and Host2 with 2 10Gbps NICs on each. One interface of Host1 is bounded with dpdk and generating traffic using pktgen. Both interfaces of Host2 are bounded with dpdk and l3fwd is running as packet forwarding application. Second NIC of Host2 is used to capture the packets. I want to breakdown the delay experienced by a packet by seeing the time spent in each interface of Host2.

Is there any way to capture packets of dpdk interfaces using l3fwd as packet forwarding applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DPDK interfaces you can make use DPDK-PDUMP capture to get packets from DPDK bonded nic. Refer `https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-16.07/sample_app_ug/pdump.html`.

Application l3fwd is to be modified with `rte_pdump_init` API call right after `rte_eal_init`. This will enable multi-proecss communication channel, there by when dpdk-pdump (secondary) application is run rte_ring and packet copy is enabled to copy the content over.

Note: please check [DPDK PDUmp App](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides-16.07/sample_app_ug/pdump.html) on usage. FOr example to copy packets from port 0 and queue 1 use `sudo ./[path to applciation]/dpdk-pdump -- --pdump 'port=0,queue=1,rx-dev=/tmp/port0_queue1.pcap'`

Answer (score 0):

pdump is good tool to capture packets at any port binded to dpdk. Launch the pdump tool as follows:

```
sudo ./build/app/dpdk-pdump -- --pdump 'port=0,queue=*,rx-dev=/tmp/capture.pcap'
```

and after packets are received, run the following command in home/temp directory to view them

```
tcpdump -nr ./capture.pcap
```

Comment: l3fwd application by default does not invoke `rte_pdump_init`. Hence running `dpdk-pdump` will not capture. I have already answered the same.